# Refresh page with google map api in react component get error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I googled the problems for a while, but still have no idea about how to fix it, the problem is first load is work fine, but when I refresh the page, sometimes it's not work and have error message,
below is my code, hope can get me some idea, thanks!!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css'

const google = window.google;

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initMap();

  }

  initMap() {
    const latLong = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    const options = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: latLong
    };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, options)
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLong,
      map,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      marginLeft: "200px",
      height: "400px",
      width: "100%",
    }
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <div id="map" style={style} ref="map"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>Google Map</title>
    <script>function initMap() {}</script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daiy7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the 5 second timer like setTimeout({},5000)

Comment: try to remove.  =initMap

Comment: I remove =initMap in <script> tag, however the problem is the same, anyway, thank you for your reply!!!